# MVC Error: The model item passed into the dictionary is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, view

I'm just trying to build a view but I'm getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   model item passed into the dictionary
>   is null, but this dictionary requires
>   a non-null model item of type
>   'System.DateTime

Now, I know why this is coming up, the particular field in the database *is* null, however it is supposed to be, as this is something that is edited at a later date. Here is my code:

**Action**

```
public ActionResult View(Int64? Id)
    {

        ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();
        var item = from t in ctn.Items where t.ItemID == Id select t;
        return View(Item.First());
    }
```

**Main View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Administrator.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<myApp.Data.Item>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    View
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% Html.RenderPartial("Details", Model); %>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">
<h1>Details - <%= Model.MainItem %></h1>
</asp:Content>
```

**Partial View**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<myApp.Data.Item>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="myApp.Supplier.Web.Extensions" %>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Information</legend>

        <div class="fieldset">

            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MainItem)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MainItem, "FormTextShort")%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Supplier.Name)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Supplier.Name, "FormTextShort")%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductCode)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductCode, "FormTextShort")%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.SubmissionDate)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.SubmissionDate, "FormDateShort")%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.SentForRepair)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.SentForRepair, "FormDateShort")%><br />
         </div>

    </fieldset>
```

In this case, the x.Product.SentForRepair date is left null, because at the time of submission, it has not yet been sent away. I have other fields like this, e.g. totalCost, etc however for simplicity I have not included them here. If I comment out the SentForRepair lines, the View displays perfectly with the other information.

I'd be so so grateful if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to get around this error!! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside the Display template you need to check for null (after making it strongly typed to `DateTime?`):

```
<% if (Model.HasValue) { %>
    <%= Html.Encode(Model.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) %>
<% } %>
```

or if you wanted to simply provide a custom date format you could remove the `FormDateShort` display template and decorate your view model property with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? SentForRepair { get; set; }
```

and then simply:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.SentForRepair)%>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks yet again for another good reply :) Just a quick question, following this view, I intend to allow the user to click on an Edit button that brings him/her to a view where he can enter in the missing data. Do you think I'll have the same problems in that view when I'm trying to display the EditorFor textboxes?

Comment: Also, just a bit more information, The model comes directly from the database, it's not a viewmodel, so I would be unsure how to implement the [DisplayFormat()] attribute above.

Comment: @109221793, concerning your first question I don't really understand what you are asking. As far as the second question is concerned, well, it doesn't matter where do your models come from, you should always use view models.

Comment: will take that advice on board re. the ViewModels. What I meant in my first comment, is following the page in my original question, I plan to display an Edit page, where the user can edit the details. In this View, I will have to display the empty fields. Should I expect the same error?

Comment: @109221793, if you check for null in the display template you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 11):

I found another solution here. Set value to be nullable.

[Telerik MVC Grid - problem with nullable DateTime property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207654/telerik-mvc-grid-problem-with-nullable-datetime-property)

```
@model System.DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new { data_datepicker = true });
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your custom Editor template for datetime from type DateTime to type nullable datetime (DateTime?)

```
@model System.DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
                      new { @class = "text-box single-line", data_datepicker="true"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changed your FormDateShort template so it takes in a DateTime? rather than a DateTime and put in some logic to check that you have a value before rendering.