# The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce open source.
So I want to add another table and I want to add another tab in Product Variant.

So I create a model.

```
 public partial class ProductVariantPriceRangeModel : BaseNopEntityModel
        {
            public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }

             [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantPriceRange.Fields.SpecialPriceStartDate")]
           [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

            public DateTime? SpecialPriceStartDate { get; set; }

             [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantPriceRange.Fields.SpecialPriceEndtDate")]
            [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

            public DateTime? SpecialPriceEndtDate { get; set; }


            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantPriceRange.Fields.Price")]

            public decimal Price1 { get; set; }
        }
```

This is my Controller.

```
[HttpPost, GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
        public ActionResult ProductVariantPriceRangeList(GridCommand command, int productVariantId)
        {
            if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
                return AccessDeniedView();

            var productVariant = _productService.GetProductVariantById(productVariantId);
            if (productVariant == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("No product variant found with the specified id");

            var productVariantPriceRange = productVariant.ProductVariantPriceRange;
            var productVariantPriceRangeModel = productVariantPriceRange
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    return new ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantPriceRangeModel()
                    {                      

                        Id = x.Id,                       
                        ProductVariantId = x.ProductVariantId,
                        SpecialPriceStartDate = x.SpecialPriceStartDate,
                        SpecialPriceEndtDate=x.SpecialPriceEndtDate,                       
                        Price1 = x.SpecialPrice
                    };
                })
                .ToList();

            var model = new GridModel<ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantPriceRangeModel>
            {
                Data = productVariantPriceRangeModel,
                Total = productVariantPriceRangeModel.Count
            };

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = model
            };
        }
```

This is my view.

```
@model ProductVariantModel
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
@using Nop.Admin;
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)



@Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("productvariant-edit").Items(x =>
{
    x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.Info").Text).Content(TabInfo().ToHtmlString()).Selected(true);
    x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.TierPrices").Text).Content(TabTierPrices().ToHtmlString());
     x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantAttributes").Text).Content(TabProductVariantAttributes().ToHtmlString());
    x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.Discounts").Text).Content(TabDiscounts().ToHtmlString());

    x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantPriceRange").Text).Content(TabProductVariantPriceRange().ToHtmlString());

    //generate an event
    EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IEventPublisher>().Publish(new AdminTabStripCreated(x, "productvariant-edit"));
})



@helper TabProductVariantPriceRange()
    {
      if (Model.Id > 0)
        {
   @(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantPriceRangeModel>()
                        .Name("productVariantPriceRange-grid")
                .DataKeys(keys =>
                {
                    keys.Add(x => x.Id);
                })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax()
                        .Select("ProductVariantPriceRangeList", "ProductVariant", new { productVariantId = Model.Id })
                        .Insert("ProductVariantPriceRangeInsert", "ProductVariant", new { productVariantId = Model.Id })
                        .Update("ProductVariantPriceRangeUpdate", "ProductVariant")
                       .Delete("ProductVariantPriceRangeDelete", "ProductVariant");
                })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.ProductVariantId)
                        .Width(100).ReadOnly()
                        .Centered();                    


                    columns.Bound(x => x.SpecialPriceStartDate)
                       .Width(200)
                        .Centered();
                    //columns.Bound(x => x.SpecialPriceEndtDate)
                    //    .Width(200)
                    //    .Centered();

                    columns.Bound(x => x.Price1)
                        .Width(100);
                    columns.Command(commands =>
                    {
                        commands.Edit();
                        commands.Delete();
                    })
                    .Width(180);


                })
                .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("onTierPriceEdit"))
                .EnableCustomBinding(true))


        }
        else
        {
    @T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.ProductVariantPriceRange.SaveBeforeEdit")
        }

}
```

When I run the programmer there is a error..

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Source Error:


Line 83:       if (Model.Id > 0)
Line 84:         {
Line 85:    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantPriceRangeModel>()
Line 86:                         .Name("productVariantPriceRange-grid")
Line 87:                 .DataKeys(keys =>
```

How can I solve it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this related post:

[Telerik MVC Grid - problem with nullable DateTime property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207654/telerik-mvc-grid-problem-with-nullable-datetime-property)

You need to modify the editor templates in Views/Shared to support a nullable datetime.